# How to use global-setup.ts to extract an email from an email generator func. , which can be passed down to all tests in playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Intent: To use same email for 2 tests --> registration and login.
Now, since I'm using an email generator for both test 2 separate emails are coming hence login fails.
I'm planning on using global-setup.ts to extract the email and pass it as setup in playwright.config.ts.

```
projects: [
        {
            name: "setup",
            testMatch: /global.setup\.ts/,
        },
        {
            name: "chromium",
            use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
            dependencies: ["setup"],
        },
]
```

How'd the global-setup.ts file look in this case?
Is there any other way to go about this?

I created global-setup.ts something like:

```
const extractRandomValues = (): {randomEmail: string } => {
    const { email }: RandomEmail = generateRandomEmail();
    return {
        randomEmail: email,
    };
};
export default async () => {
    global.sharedValues = extractRandomValues();
};
```

In this case i'm getting error for sharedValues: User
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017)

Answer (score 1):

**globalSetup** is just a function that runs before test files. There's no way to access its data.
But you can generate an email and save it into a file, which can be read later in your tests if that's the case.

It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. If you need to test registration - write a single test for registration. If you need a login test, write a single test that performs registration and authentication. Or two tests in `test.describe.serial` mode, where email generated in **beforeAll**.

If you need to create an account before all your tests run - create an account in globalSetup, save the storage state, and reuse it in tests.